# Force.com IDE not displaying custom fields, recordtype section under custom/standard object

Tags: custom-object, custom-field, eclipse, force.com-ide

I'm using eclipse-dsl-kepler-SR2-win32 and Force.com IDE http://media.developerforce.com/force-ide/eclipse42. In the Custom/ Standard object section, individual custom fields , recordtype etc are not shbowing up. Please advise.

Comment: a screen shot of what you are seeing would be helpful

Comment: It sounds like you either didn't select the fields to download to your IDE OR, you had an error when the metadata was retrieved. Did you receive an error message when retrieving the metadata? Try refreshing your project by selecting the objects where you're not seeing what you want and make certain everything you want is selected for retrieval.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found a workaround:

To retrieve objects along with your custom metadata, you have to manually add necessary objects to your Eclipse package.xml file. 
For example, to retrieve a custom object MyObject__c (with all fields, validation rules, record types etc), you should add:

```
<types>
    <members>MyObject__c</members>
    <name>CustomObject</name>
</types>
```